# Basis of $M_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ formed of diagonalizable matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, change-of-basis

I've the following question
$$
\text{Does it exist a basis of }M_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\text{ constituted of diagonalizable matrix ?}
$$

My idea was to keep $E_{ii}$ on my basis, and maybe summing $E_{ij}+E_{ji}$ to have for sure a diagonalizable matrix but some vector of the basis are missing, how can I find them ?

Comment: See what you can do for $M_2(\mathbb R)$ first.

Comment: I've taken $a_{ii}=E_{ii}$ and $a_{ij}=E_{ij}+E_{jj}$ does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and the field is unimportant. Note that when $i\ne j$, each $E_{ij}$ is the sum of two diagonalisable matrices:
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&-1}+\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}.
$$
Therefore, the union of $\{E_{ii}\}$ and $\{E_{ij}-E_{\max(i,j),\,\max(i,j)}: i\ne j\}$ form a basis of the whole matrix space and each member in the basis is diagonalisable.

Comment: How can I justify it still is a basis ?

Comment: @Atmos There are $n^2$ of them and they span the whole matrix space.

Comment: Why does it span ?

Comment: @Atmos Every $A$ can be written as a linear combination of the $E_{ij}$s, and each $E_{ij}$ is a linear combination of the basis "vectors" in my answer.

Comment: Aaaah true ! But can we choose $E_{ij}+E_{jj}$ ? for me, we would have a matrix with trace $\ne 0$ and with $n-1$ columns null, so it is diagonalizable ? Am i wrong ?

Comment: @Atmos Do you mean $\{E_{ii}\}\cup\{E_{ij}+E_{\max(i,j),\,\max(i,j)}: i\ne j\}$? If so, of course. We can write $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1}-\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}$ instead.

Comment: No I mean $\left\{E_ii\right\} \cup \left\{E_{i,j}+E_{jj}\right\}$ is that good ?

Comment: @Atmos Yes, why not? You may write $\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&0}-\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ as well.